# What is wrong with my park_car function?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, heap-memory

I'm again doing a task for school and I'm implementing it slowly, I don't know why my `park_car` function is not working, I just wanted to make a test and the program crashes ... here is my code.

PS: I can't change the `***p2parkboxes` because it is given in the starter file like most other variables. I just want to see the first element of Floor 0 as : HH-AB 1234. Your help is most appreciated.
PS2: I can't use the std::string as well it isn't allowed for the task.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

#define EMPTY "----------"
class Parkbox{
    char *license_plate; // car's license plate
    public:
    Parkbox(char *s = EMPTY); // CTOR
    ~Parkbox(); // DTOR
    char *get_plate(){return license_plate;}
};
class ParkingGarage{
    Parkbox ***p2parkboxes;
    //int dimensions_of_parkhouse[3]; // better with rows,columns,floors
    int rows,columns,floors; // dimensions of park house
    int total_num_of_cars_currently_parked;
    int next_free_parking_position[3];
    // PRIVATE MEMBER FUNCTION
    void find_next_free_parking_position();
    public:
    ParkingGarage(int row, int col, int flr);// CTOR,[rows][columns][floors]
    ~ParkingGarage(); // DTOR
    bool park_car(char*); // park car with license plate
    bool fetch_car(char*); // fetch car with license plate
    void show(); // show content of garage floor
    // by floor
};

Parkbox::Parkbox(char *s ) { // CTOR
    license_plate = new char[strlen(s)+1];
    strcpy(license_plate, s);
    //cout << "ParkBox CTOR" << endl;
}
Parkbox::~Parkbox() { // DTOR
    delete [] license_plate;
    //cout << "ParkBox DTOR" << endl;
}

ParkingGarage::ParkingGarage(int row, int col, int flr){
    rows = row; columns = col; floors = flr;
    p2parkboxes = new Parkbox**[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        p2parkboxes[i] = new Parkbox*[col];

        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
            p2parkboxes[i][j] = new Parkbox[flr];
    }

}

ParkingGarage::~ParkingGarage(){

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
            delete [] p2parkboxes[i][j];

        delete [] p2parkboxes[i];
    }
    delete [] p2parkboxes;
}

void ParkingGarage::show(){
    int i,j,k;
    for (i = 0 ; i < floors; i++){
        cout << "Floor" << i << endl;
        for (j=0;j<rows;j++){
            for (k=0;k<columns;k++){
                cout << p2parkboxes[j][k][i].get_plate() << "  ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

bool ParkingGarage::park_car(char*s){

    p2parkboxes[0][0][0] = Parkbox(s); //test
    //p2parkboxes[0][0][0] = s; //test

    return true;
}


int main(void) {
    // a parking garage with 2 rows, 3 columns and 4 floors
    ParkingGarage pg1(2, 3, 4);
    pg1.park_car("HH-AB 1234");
    /*pg1.park_car("HH-CD 5678");
      pg1.park_car("HH-EF 1010");
      pg1.park_car("HH-GH 1235");
      pg1.park_car("HH-IJ 5676");
      pg1.park_car("HH-LM 1017");
      pg1.park_car("HH-MN 1111"); */
    pg1.show();
    /*pg1.fetch_car("HH-CD 5678");
      pg1.show();
      pg1.fetch_car("HH-IJ 5676");
      pg1.show();
      pg1.park_car("HH-SK 1087");
      pg1.show();
      pg1.park_car("SE-AB 1000");
      pg1.show();
      pg1.park_car("PI-XY 9999");
      pg1.show(); */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: `Parkbox ***p2parkboxes;` o_O  While you say that you can't change that declaration, you should change it anyway.  It's best to avoid multidimensional, dynamically allocated arrays in C++.  Prefer to use a single dimensional array (or, if you must, a `vector<vector<vector<ParkBox>>>`).  I'd hazard to guess that it would be easier to argue to your instructor that the triple pointer is insane than it would be to implement this class correctly.

Comment: Better use `std::string` instead of plain `char*`.

Comment: For future reference, please don't delete your original problem when it gets solved (it makes your question useless to future visitors). Also when you want a code review there's a site for that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question is still here, thanks for the review link!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not declare the copy constructor for the Parkbox class. So, the line

```
p2parboxes[0][0][0] = Parkbox(s)
```

creates something (instance of Parkbox with a char* pointer) on the stack (and deletes it almost immediately).  To correct this you might define the

```
Parkbox& operator = Parkbox(const Parkbox& other)
{
    license_plate = new char[strlen(other.get_plate())+1];
    strcpy(license_plate, other.get_plate());
    return *this;
}
```

Let's see the workflow for the

```
p2parboxes[0][0][0] = Parkbox(s)
```

line.

1. First, the constructor is called and an instance of Parkbox is created on stack (we will call this tmp_Parkbox).
2. Inside this constructor the license_plate is allocated and let's say it points to 0xDEADBEEF location.
3. The copying happens (this is obvious because *this* is the thing that is written in code) and the p2parboxes[0][0][0] now contains the exact copy of tmp_Parkbox.
4. The scope for tmp_Parkbox now ends and the destructor for tmp_Parkbox is called, where the tmp_Parkbox.license_plate (0xDEADBEEF ptr) is deallocated.
5. p2parboxes[0][0][0] still contains a "valid" instance of Parkbox and the p2parboxes[0][0][0].license_plate is still 0xDEADBEEF which leads to the undefined behaviour, if any allocation occurs before you call the

   cout << p2parboxes[0][0][0].license_plate;

Bottom line: there is nothing wrong with the line itself, the problem is hidden within the implementation details of the '=' operator.

At this point it is really better for you to use the std::string for strings and not the razor-sharp, tricky and explicit C-style direct memory management mixed with the implicit C++ copy/construction semantics. The code would also be better if you use the std::vector for dynamic arrays.

Comment: Don't forget to delete the current license_plate, though!  Otherwise you get a memory leak.  You also need to carefully check for self assignment or you risk undefined behavior.

Comment: Sure, Chris. My code only "fixes" the problem, introducing another one :) Maybe with C++11 the move constructor would be better here with the direct copy of the license_plate ptr and no strcpy() call.

Comment: _creates something (instance of Parkbox with a char* pointer) on the stack (and deletes it almost immediately)._ Why on the stack?It should be on heap, because in Parkbox CTOR Im allocating memory for every license_plate ...

Comment: The license_plate will be in heap definitely. The thing is that the very pointer (license_plate in temporary stack-allocated Parkbox) is lost in assignment. Actually, you have a new instance of Parkbox in p2parboxes[0][0][0] and this instance points to "something" (using byte-by-byte copy in autogenerated copy operator) which is deallocated, because the temporary Parkbox is deleted.

Comment: I've added the detailed description. Hope now everything it is clear.

Comment: Thank you now I have a better understanding but the prof forbid std::string and did not introduce std::vector yet so probably that is also forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you do not have deep copy assignment semantics.  When you assign a temporary Parkbox to the Parkbox in the parking garage, the compiler generated assignment operator makes a shallow copy of the pointer license_plate, leaving both Parkboxes pointing at the same memory location.  Then the temporary Parkbox goes out of scope and deletes license_plate.  Since the other Parkbox is pointing at the same spot its license_plate gets deleted, too.

There are a couple solutions.  One way to solve the problem is to define an assignment operator and a copy constructor that provide proper semantics, i.e. that perform deep copies of the license plate string.  The better option, and the one that makes better use of C++, is to use std::strings instead of manually allocated C-strings.  I strongly suggest the second approach, though working through the first might be instructive.

Comment: Unfortunately, std::string is not allowed for this task :(

Answer (score 0):

From the OP:

I solved the Problem with :

```
void Parkbox::change_plate(char *s){
delete [] license_plate;
license_plate = new char[strlen(s)+1];
strcpy(license_plate, s);
}
```